# Google cloud-ml stuck without logs after several iterations

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

I am training a TF ML job on cloud-ml, and it seems the job is stuck after a few iterations (900 iterations). Surprisingly, when I run the code locally it works fine, and also hyper tuning on GCP continues training but runs slower than my local laptop which has a 1060GTX GPU.
I am also using the runtime version 1.6.

I changed the scale-tier and it doesn't help. What can be the issue?

Comment: Do you know which operation your code got stuck on? It might be the case that the stuck operation may not be able to access files on GCS. If you are not able to figure it out, can you share your project and job id with cloudml-feedback@google.com please? We can inspect the logs and start further discussion from there.

Comment: Also, with reference to the performance, can you please note the scale tier/machine configuration in your question?

Comment: Were you able to solve the issue?

Comment: We followed this by email, and the final suggestion was to use Keras instead of TensorFlow.

Comment: We could manage to work with basic-gpu with the TensorFlow code, but not the distributed standard_1 scale tier